# Using Conditional operator inside a string?

Tags: c#, escaping, stringbuilder, conditional-operator

How do I use a conditional operator inside a string?

Why is the value of this string missing `TO_DATE(` and `'` the single quote? and what can I do to fix it?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//code...
sb.AppendLine("     '" + txtStatus.Text + "',");
sb.AppendLine("     TO_DATE(" + dtpEligDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") == "" ? "null" : dtpEligDate.Value.ToString() + "),");
sb.AppendLine("     '" + txtCoverageEndReason.Text == "" ? "null" : txtCoverageEndReason.Text + "',");
//code...
```

String value:

```
'',
7/19/2013 9:04:35 AM),
',
```

My understanding is that this is NOT caused by lack of escaping charecters, but because of the use of a conditional operator.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), add `()` to your ternary operator and it will work:

```
sb.AppendLine("TO_DATE(" + 
    (dtpEligDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") == "" ? "null" : dtpEligDate.Value.ToString()) + 
"),");
```

Basicaly it will first concatenate strings (`+`) and then evaluate conditional statement (`?:`), but you expect it to be opposite. Parentheses will *fix* it.

As a side note: it'd be better to use parametrized queries.